# Why AWS S3 return error message Access Denied?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When I upload file in aws s3 it return me this error

```
{
"message": "Access Denied",
"code": "AccessDenied",
"region": null,
"time": "2018-09-29T19:31:29.411Z",
"requestId": "A26BAEB25BCD657B",
"extendedRequestId": "RYeX9fiif5V/DmIpYq9umUi0vZlCyywbDjf5hLctKOzg6cRWJRXQDAYEU+S7sL9snnr7rxD/P8c=",
"statusCode": 403,
"retryable": false,
"retryDelay": 68.10123280572672
}
```

I work with node js.

Comment: Do you own the bucket to which you are uploading? How are you uploading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of possible causes for AccessDenied from S3:

1. Policy associated with credentials does not allow access
2. Policy associated with bucket denies access
3. Object does not exist
4. Object is KMS-encrypted and you didn't supply KMS key
5. Object is in another account and your cross-account permissions do not allow access
6. VPC endpoint policy
7. Requester Pays is enabled on bucket
8. AWS Organizations service control policy does not allow access

And some ideas on [how to troubleshoot 403 Access Denied](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/).